# ASP.NET MVC WebAPI Hosted in the Same Project as Classic Controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, name-conflict

I want to use classic MVC controllers alongside WebAPI controllers in the same project.
The classic MVC controllers will return static content, like the HTML for pages.
All data will be passed around with the WebAPI.

The problem is that the controller class names end up being the same.
Since WebAPI sticks `API/` in the front, there's no routing conflict.
I thought about creating an area and just adjusting the routing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realized I can just create a new folder called ApiControllers at the top level of the project.
Then all the WebAPI controllers are created under a different namespace.
I didn't have to touch any routing information or anything.
Simple...

Comment: That's what I do too.